# How to declare an optional get parameter in Serverless Lambda?

Tags: http, lambda, serverless

I'd like to understand if there's a quick syntax for defining a optional pathParameter in serverless (to deploy on AWS lambda).

here's what I have in my functions

functions:

```
 MyFunc:

    handler: handler.myFunc

    events:

      - http:

          path: /getdata/{my_id}

          method: get

          request:

            parameters:

              paths:

                my_id: true
```

I've found around the internet a trick to define optional param like:

```
          path: /getdata/{?my_id}
```

but it's not working for serverless.
And I'm getting back this error on deploy:

```
 Resource's path part only allow a-zA-Z0-9._- and curly braces at the beginning and the end.
```

I was also wondering if changing:

```
 my_id: false
```

would be my case (but it is not)

What's then the serverless way to have my_id optional so both http call:

```
http://.../getdata
http://.../getdata/12345
```

will be managed by  MyFunc?

Hope there's a cleaner solution from the need to create two different endpoints/func/lambda

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define two events.

```
MyFunc:
  handler: handler.myFunc
  events:
    - http:
        path: /getdata/
        method: GET
    - http:
        path: /getdata/{id}
        method: GET
```

Then the path variable `id` will work with API Gateway. In your lambda code check for `event.pathParameters.id`. Be careful, because `event.pathParameters` does not have to be defined if `id` is not presented.

**Update:**

Having

```
request:
  parameters:
    paths:
      id: false
```

in serverless yaml does not have any impact on generated CloudFormation template. You can check it yourself using `sls package -p /package/dir`.

Comment: thanks, yes this is working... even though it's not so clean... btw do you have an idea of what's the purpose of "true" in my_id: true ?

Comment: I think it only works with query strings. As far as I know, API Gateway does not support optional path parameters, only optional query string parameters.
[Documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#request-parameters) is not really clear about this though. :)